# Solving a problem using Cauchy's residue theorem, is there more to it?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_1,...z_n$ be distinct complex numbers. Let $C$ be a circle around $z_1$ such that no other $z_j$ is in $C$ for $j>1$. Let $$f(z) = (z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_n)$$ Find $\oint_{C}{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{f(z)}}$.

Attempt: Using Cauchy's Residue Theorem, and $$g(z) = \dfrac{1}{f(z)}$$ we see that $g(z)$ is analytic inside and on $C$ (assuming no $z_j$ is on $C$ for $j>1$) except for $z=z_1$ $$\oint_{C}{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{f(z)}}=\oint_{C}{g(z)}\ \mathrm{d}z=2\pi\textbf{i}\ \phi(z_1)$$ where$$\phi(z) = \dfrac{1}{(z-z_2)(z-z_3)...(z-z_n)}$$ $$\therefore \phi(z_1) = \dfrac{1}{(z_1-z_2)...(z_1-z_n)}$$

Any faults with this? Or something that I should add?

Comment: There is something you should add: the factor $2\pi i$.

Comment: what you have looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy's Residue theorem states:

> Let $C$ be a simple closed contour, oriented in a positive direction.
>   If a function is analytic inside and on $C$ except for a finite number
>   of singular points denoted by $z_k\ \forall\ k \in \{1,2..n\}$ then:
>   $$\oint_C f(z)\ \mathrm{d}z = 2\pi \textbf{i}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathrm{Res}_{z=z_k}f(z)$$

From Brown and Churchill, Complex Variables and applications.

From what you've written:

> Let $C$ be a circle around $z_1$ such that no other $z_j$ is in $C$ for $j>1$.

I understand that the Contour $C$ encloses $z=z_1$ and that all other points, $z_j$ with $j>1$ do *not* reside in $C$. Therefore we need to find the residue at $z=z_1$ and *only* at that point. Because it is the only point in the area enclosed by the Contour for which the function "blows up". For that we can use your method:

Let $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$ for which we have:

$$\oint_C g(z)\ \mathrm{d}z = 2\pi \textbf{i}\ \mathrm{Res}_{z=z_1}\frac{1}{f(z)}$$

To find the residue, apply the theorem:

> An isolated singular point $z_0$ of some
>   function $f$ is a pole of order $m$ iff $f(z)$ can be expressed
>   thusly: $$f(z)=\frac{\phi{(z)}}{(z-z_0)^m}$$

In our case $z_0$ is $z_1$, which is isolated by virtue of the contour we have chosen to enclose it. So our isolated point is $z_1$ and the pole is simple, i.e. $m=1$

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)} = \frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_1)}$$

From here we see that we can indeed express our function in the form indicated and that $\phi(z)$ is in fact $\frac{1}{(z-z_2)...(z-z_n)}$.

So the Residue is simply:

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=z_1}g(z) = \phi(z_1) = \frac{1}{(z_1-z_2)...(z_1-z_n)}$$

So:

$$\oint_C f(z)\ \mathrm{d}z = 2\pi \textbf{i}\ \phi(z_1) = \frac{2\pi \textbf{i}}{{(z_1-z_2)...(z_1-z_n)}}$$

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not correct.  Why do you think $\phi(z_1) = 1$?  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles) for instance.

Comment: @AntonioVargas ah. wow i made a really stupid error. i've fixed it in the edit.